# JavaScript TypeError, Cannot read property of undefined, but the function is defined. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, function, object

I keep getting the error:
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

The error is in this line: "this.courseName.push(dish);"

Here is the code:

```
let menu = {
    _courses: {
      _appetizers:[] ,
      _mains:[],
      _desserts: []
    },

    addDishToCourse(courseName, dishName, dishPrice){
        const dish = { name: this.dishName, price: this.dishPrice };

        // ERROR HERE: **this._courses[courseName].push(dish);**
    },
};
```

I have been stuck with this error for hours. Is there something I'm not seeing?

Sorry if there is a simple solution to this. I'm relatively new to JavaScript.

**Edit:**

I was indeed calling the key incorrectly. I am now calling the function as:

```
  menu.addDishToCourse("_appetizers", "random", 10);
  console.log(menu._courses._appetizers);
```

When I log this in compiler it returns:

```
    [ { name: undefined, price: undefined } ]
```

It seems like the function isn't getting called. Am I approaching this fundamentally incorrectly?

Comment: `this._courses[courseName]` is undefined.  What is the value of `courseName`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lxg99me0/3/ works for me, it alerts undefined because you are setting `dish` wrong but there is no errors in console. Post how you call that function, you are most likely passing the wrong courseName

Comment: `courseName` does not seem to be present in `_courses`. Thats why it is undefined.

Comment: how are you calling it? I think you are passing a wrong `key` name in `courseName`.

Comment: I am running this on Code Academy. I want this to return an array and display that array. 
Currently, it's just returning undefined.



I was indeed calling the key incorrectly. I am now calling the function as: 
 
      menu.addDishToCourse("_appetizers", "random", 10);
      console.log(menu._courses._appetizers);

When I log this in compiler it returns:

        [ { name: undefined, price: undefined } ]


It seems like the function isn't getting called. Am I approaching this fundamentally incorrectly?

Comment: @In fact you are assigning wrong values, to object to push in your courses array when you used `{ name: this.dishName, price: this.dishPrice }`. Check [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49310050/3669624) for a better explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that you were passing a wrong `courseName` to the function, that's why you get the error.

And your second problem is that you are assigning wrong values, to object to push in your courses array when you used `{ name: this.dishName, price: this.dishPrice }`.

In fact when you use `this.dishName` you were trying to get `dishName` from your `menu` object that's why it's `undefined`, you just need to use the parameters `dishName` and `dishPrice` you are passing arguments to the function.

```
    const dish = {
      name: dishName,
      price: dishPrice
    };

    this._courses[courseName].push(dish);
```

This is a working Demo:

```js
let menu = {
  _courses: {
    _appetizers: [],
    _mains: [],
    _desserts: []
  },

  addDishToCourse(courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {
    const dish = {
      name: dishName,
      price: dishPrice
    };

    this._courses[courseName].push(dish);
  },
};


menu.addDishToCourse("_appetizers", "random", 10);
console.log(menu._courses._appetizers);
```

Comment: I thought I'd just said that earlier :)

Comment: @StevePadmore In fact it was not a scope problem, it was wrong values problem, instead of passing the arguments of the function. :)

Comment: I agree, that the wrong values were passed, but that was because 'this' was used, and the variables used are not in the scope of 'this', but in the function itself. I think it's just semantics, but the answer is still the same :)

Comment: @CookieDoe Cool, glad it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is the `scope` that is the issue.

`this` is the `object` itself (the menu in this case) and has `_courses` and `addDishToCourse` as its properties.

Inside the `addDishToCourse` `this` is looking at the `object` for the `dishName` and `dishPrice`, but they are scoped to the function itself (from the parameters).

So the correct code would be like so:

```
let menu = {
        _courses: {
            _appetizers: [],
            _mains: [],
            _desserts:[]
        },

        addDishToCourse(courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {
            const dish = { name: dishName, price: dishPrice };

            this._courses[courseName].push(dish);
        }
    }    

menu.addDish("_mains", "Pizza", "10");
```

Comment: Actually this is not a scope problem, it was wrong values problem, instead of passing the arguments of the function.

Comment: Scope as in dishName and dishPrice are not in the scope of the object (so this.dishName is undefined), but in the scope of the function (just dishName is correct).

Comment: Maybe, you are right as well, as they are part of the object scope ;) You are still right:)

Comment: And you as well ;)